# How to store words in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to store an array of words in C

To be more specific i want to form an array like this:

```
a_cool_array_name={"first","second","third","fourth","fifth"};
```

i tried using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /*i have tried using both single and double quotation marks */

    char array1[4];
    array1[0]='hello';
    array1[1]='world';
    array1[2]='its';
    array1[3]='me';
    printf("%s",array1[0]);
}
```

> I have tried using both single and double quotations however **BOTH** fail

In the single quotations the program crashes the moment i try to build and run it. In case of double quotation marks the program doesn't even compile at all.
It throws up an error which looks something like this

> 8:11: error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Whats the difference in using single and double quotations in strings and such? 
**AND**

How do i make an array of words?

Is there any other way of storing words other 2D array? which pretty messes some things up... :(

Comment: `char` is not a string type.

Comment: What you need is a 2 dimensional array of chars. Char array_name[4][length of words]. Because "first" is already array of chars.

Comment: @Arc676 his question is so basic, you're answer will only confuse him more :)

Comment: @iharob i tried using `string` instead of `char` which is pretty stupid and it failed as expected...

Comment: @VedantKashyap There is no `string` type in [tag:c].

Comment: Don't trial and error in programming in general and never in C specifically. Learn the language. Most C books include some kind of lesson how to store the words in a text or similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You use single quotation marks for single chars: `'c' 'd'` etc, and you use double quotation marks for strings like `"first"`.
2. What you want to use here is matrix, or 2 dimensional array of chars:

   ```
   char array[10][20];
   ```

And now in `array[0]` is array of 20 characters. You can use this as you would normal array. For example: `array[0][0]` in code below gives you `'f'`.

```
char array[][20] = {"first","second","third","fourth","fifth"};
```

And now:

`printf("%s\n",array[0]);` would give you "first"

Answer (score 5):

You almost had it, to define an array of strings you can do this<sup>1</sup>

```
const char *array[] = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"};
```

Also please consider:

1. The single quotes are used to get an `int` that corresponds to the ascii value of a single character and is called a character constant. Multiple characeters enclosed by single quotes are called *multicharaceter constants* and also give you an `int` value, the value being *implementation defined*.
2. When using string literals like the ones initializing the array above, always use `const`. That will help you prevent modifying them which is illegal.

There is no *string* type in [c](/questions/tagged/c). To have strings you need to understand what they are and how they work. A [c](/questions/tagged/c) string is nothing but a sequence (*array if you will*) of non-`\0` bytes followed by a `'\0'` that marks the end of it.

In the code above you have 5 strings, take for example `"first"`, it consists of the following sequence

```
{'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '\0'}
```

the terminating `'\0'` is very important.

So you create an array of pointers to *strings*, but strings in the sense explained above.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>An array of `char` poitners, initialized with string literals. So it's an array of `char` pointers pointing to string literals.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In C, text strings are stored as arrays of characters. If you are dealing with strings of variable length, you can use pointers to refer to them. Here's how to do it for your example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *array1[4]; // use const because we're pointing to literals

    array1[0] = "hello";
    array1[1] = "world";
    array1[2] = "its";
    array1[3] = "me";

    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", array1[0], array1[1], array1[2], array1[3]);
}
```

`array1` is an array of 4 pointers to strings. Each pointer is initialized to point to a different literal string. Use double quotes (not single quotes) to create literal strings in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, hope this will help you:

```
main()
{

int i;
char item[30][10]={"Chickpeas","Rice","Semolina","Wheat","Almond","Sapota","Dates","Asafetida","Garlic","Chilly","\0"};

int amt[10];

for(i=0;i<10;i++){

printf("Please enter the price for %s:", item[i]);

scanf("%d",&amt[i]);

}

printf("\n\n\nAmount per item is ");

for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    printf("%s: %d\n",item[i],amt[i]);

}

dscnt=0;
getch();


}
```

Comment: hi @ashim-nath, please explain your answer as we have no ideas about what is doing ... Thank you